# Android App Banner Not Showing

Tags: android, smartbanner

I've tried this android app banner on

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/increasing-engagement-with-app-install-banners-in-chrome-for-android

This is my manifest file :

```js
{
 "short_name": "App",
 "name": "Long App Name",
 "icons": [{
  "src": "images/logo.png",
  "sizes": "144x144",
  "type": "image/png"
 }],
 "start_url": "/order",
 "prefer_related_applications": true,
 "related_applications": [{
  "platform": "play",
  "id": "android id here"
 }]
}
```

But it's not working on android chrome

There are several steps that I already tried :

1. Enable chrome://flags/#bypass-app-banner-engagement-checks
2. I also already check on chrome inspect element on Application tab, my manifest.json is exist..

Here how I link it on html page

```html
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
```

Are the source of this problem because >>

1. The android id/app that i choose is not available in my region eventhough it's enable on my client?
2. I read it's must https, are this must really secure? I know my https staging server is got NET::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID (expired date)?